# Flutter Debugging Apps stuck at observatory listening on *********** on Vivo Phones after an OS Update

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, debugging

Flutter hot restart and hot reload is not working after an OS Update to Android 11 - Vivo Y11. All the new and old debugging apps are stuck at `I/flutter ( 6795): Observatory listening on ***********`

Device Restarted
Vscode restarted
Android studio tested
debugging app opens and works when disconnected from pc

Comment: This is from probably from inside your code. add more code to the question.

Comment: @NisanthReddy but if i use android studio emulator it can work only if i use adb wifi using smartphone have such problem

Comment: You mean to say that the app is not opening or something is not working ? It just seems like your phone isn't correctly connected to your development device.

Comment: Same issue with me, this started happening after I updated my phone Vivo v20 to latest version. Native android apps are working completely fine on mobile phone. Only flutter apps get stuck with black background and this given message.

Comment: @AsfarAli I can confirm that. Started happening with me as well. I have vivo y11. And after update, flutter hot reload is no longer working. Gets stuck at Observatory listening on ************************************

Comment: I have seen that this issue occurred with some other vivo phones as well.

Comment: @afrozopsydev did you find any fix? have same phone same update issue

Comment: @RajeshJr. naah. I didn't find a fix. I just abandoned that cellphone and shifted over to Samsung. Vivo devices are big no for me from now on.